# Angular - Best approach for sending partial data model in HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, casting, typescript-typings

Server returns a User object in response

```
{ 
  name: "some_name",
  age: 30
}
```

I'll create a class for the User object, but the class also have other property which I need only in the client side

```
class User {
  public color: string = "red"
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
}
```

color property I'll only use in client-side.

Now User type for client and server are different.

If I want to send User obj back to the server without color property, in request method

1. Should I create a new class Object from User?

```
class UserRequest {
constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
}

let userRequest = new UserRequest(user.name, user.age);
```

2. Just create new object without type?

```
let userRequest = {
  name: user.name,
  age: user.age
}
```

Here I have only 2 property, If I have more then will this feasible?

Assume If I have to send a list of User then iterating all the user object creating a new object will increase complexity.

What is the best approach when types are different?

Comment: you can type things without the need to construct an object, just create a UserRequest interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new function in your `User` class that will return only the database fields, or make it more generic by defining a `dbFields` array that contains only the fields that need to be sent to the server:

```js
class User {
  public color: string = "red";
  private dbFields = ['name', 'age'];
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}

  getUserData(){
    let data = {};
    for(const field of this.dbFields)
      data[field]=this[field];
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply call `user.getUserData()` and it will return an object with only `name` and `age`

You can also make it more general by defining a `Model` class and use the function in other models as well:

```js
class Model {
  constructor(protected dbFields: string[]) {}

  getDatabaseData(){
    let data = {};
    for(const field of this.dbFields)
      data[field]=this[field];
    return data;
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  public color: string = "red";
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
    super(['name', 'age']);
  }
}
```

And you call `user.getDatabaseData()` when you want to send a request.

If you have more fields, you just add more values to the `dbFields` array. If you have an array of users, you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to an array of database data:

```js
const usersData = users.map((user: User)=>user.getDatabaseData());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.post<ServerModel>({ serverModel.prop1: clientModel.prop1, serverModel.prop2: clientModel.prop2 });
```

If you need to create server model in more than one spot you can wrap it in a function. Seeing you are using classes you could have a method called toServerModel but the Angular standard is to use interfaces for data models, not classes.